# Google Protobuf-c repeated strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, protocol-buffers

My Google protobuf-c proto file looks like this:

```
message foo{
  required uint32 addresscount= 1;
  repeated string destination_hops= 2;
}
```

I want an array of strings and `addresscount` is supposed to give the count of array elements.

The generated protobuf-h file is

```
struct  _foo
   {
   ProtobufCMessage base;
   uint32_t addresscount;
   size_t n_destination_hops;
   char **destination_hops;
   };
```

I assume that n_destination_hops is the number of times the string destination_hops appears in the message. I had kept addresscount for that purpose and i guess thats not required. My question is this:

`char **destination_hops` is a pointer to an array of `char *` pointers. Each index can be of different length. How will protobuf know the size of each `char *` pointer when it has packed this into a stream. Does protobuf assume that all destination_hops would be of the same size and is that given by `size_t n_destination_hops`?

DOUBT 2:

`char ** destination_hops` is an array of `char *` pointers.

This means i can look at it as `char *destination_hops[0]`, `char *destination_hops[1]`, etc

If this is correct then shouldn't i be able to set `char *destination_hops[0] = "abc"`.

When i do that i get a segmentation fault.

Any idea why?

Comment: Which C implementation of protobufs are you using?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that `n_destination_hops` is the number of times the string `destination_hops` appears in the message.

Yep.

> I had kept `addresscount` for that purpose and i guess thats not required.

Right.

> `char **destination_hops` is a pointer to an array of `char *` pointers. Each index can be of different length. How will protobuf know the size of each `char *` pointer when it has packed this into a stream.

In the wire representation of the string, it is preceded by the string's length, coded as a packed integer. In memory, they are just ordinary zero-terminated C strings, so:

- `NUL` is not a valid character in the string
- the length can be computed with `strlen`

Protobuf requires that the value of a `string` be a sequence of UTF-8 encoded characters. If you want to include `NUL` or bytes which are not part of a valid UTF-8 sequence, use `bytes` instead of `string`. If you do that, the in-memory datastructure will include an explicit length.

> Shouldn't i be able to set `char *destination_hops[0]` = `"abc"`

I suppose you mean that you should be able to write:

```
destination_hops[0] = "abc";
```

That's valid C, but it requires that `destination_hops` have at least one element. A newly initialized `foo` will have `n_destination_hops = 0;` and `destination_hops = NULL;`, in which case trying to access `destination_hops[0]` will try to dereference `NULL`, which is a segfault. (Or UB, if you prefer.9